# How to pass variable to ngif

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

header.component.html

```
      <ng-container *ngFor="let headerMenu of headerMenus">
    <li *ngIf="headerMenu.ngif">
      <a (click)="onClick(headerMenu.menu)" [class]="headerMenu.menu">
        <img [src]="headerMenu.src" [alt]="headerMenu.menu">
        <p>{{ headerMenu.menu | uppercase }}</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
```

headerMenu.service.ts

```
  public headerMenus: HeaderMenu[] = [
// menu, srcURL, ngif
new HeaderMenu('service', 'assets/img/service.png', true),
new HeaderMenu('pricing', 'assets/img/pricing.png', true),
new HeaderMenu('source', 'assets/img/source.png', true),
new HeaderMenu('about', 'assets/img/about.png', true),
new HeaderMenu('user', 'assets/img/user.png', 'isLoggedIn'),
new HeaderMenu('login', 'assets/img/login.png', 'isLoggedIn'),
```

];

I am trying to pass "isLoggedIn" variable to ngif as headerMenu.ngif.
I was expecting "isLoggedIn" work as a variable so that it can be turned on and off depends on the login status.

But what it actually does is that it recognized as a string "isLoggedIn".

is there any way I can pass it as a variable?

Comment: Assuming `isLoggedIn` is a property of the `headerMenu` service, try `this.isLoggedIn` (no quotes).

Comment: The problem of the way you say is that it will stick into true or false.

 I want to pass variable and it acts like *ngIf="isLoggedIn" so that it can react dynamically to "isLoggedIn" property in header.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your passing the string literal 'isLoggedIn'. In your headerMenu.service.ts file where the new HeaderMenu are declared is isLoggedIn a local variable class variable or where is it declared? If it is a class member you can access it by:

```
new HeaderMenu('login', 'assets/img/login.png', this.isLoggedIn)
```

Or or if it its coming from a dataservice injected into your class like below:

```
constructor(public dataService:DataService){}
```

then you would access it like this:

```
new HeaderMenu('login', 'assets/img/login.png', dataService.isLoggedIn)
```